# How to execute "select bool expression" in SQL Server, like select 1>0 in Mysql?

Tags: sql-server

How to execute "select bool expression" in SQL Server, like select 1>0 in Mysql?

select 1>0 cause a compile error in SQL server.

Comment: There's no user visible bool *data type* in T-SQL. The only place you can freely write bool *expressions* are in *predicates* (`WHERE` clauses, `WHEN` clauses of `CASE` expressions, `CHECK` constraints, etc)

Comment: What's the point of `SELECT 1>0`? What are you trying to do? MySQL has a *lot* of non-standard extensions or even outright bugs that surface as "features". MySQL doesn't have a `boolean` type like PostgreSQL does

Comment: seems like can use select 1 where 1=2 to execute the bool expression

Comment: @AiresLiu you still haven't explained what you are trying to do. Filter stuff? Use a condition in the `WHERE` clause. Return 1 or 0? Use `CASE` in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Sometimes I want to check the result of the bool expression in where clause, but the whole SQL statement is too complicated, so I want to validate the bool expression using origin value in simple select bool expression like in  MySQL.

Comment: @AiresLiu: Unrelated, but: MySQL has not "bool expressions". It simply treats any value that can be converted to a number greater than zero as "true" and everything else as "false". e.g.  `'this is wrong'` is treated as "false" and  `'1 or the other'` is treated as "true".

Comment: @AiresLiu you still haven't explained what you are doing. And using a `SELECT` to calculate a condition does nothing more than add 8 extra characters. And probably cause a huge delay by preventing the server from using indexes. What does the query look like?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that subqueries within exists never return data, it has only two stated either true or False.Therefore, it will never be evaluated.

You can see various example

```
select * from table where exists(select 1)
```

or

```
select * from table where exists(select 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I can use `select 1 where bool expression` with origin data to check the bool expression value.

If the bool expression is true, it returns 1.

If the bool expression is false, it returns null.

Thanks.

Comment: No, the problem wasn't solved. The problem wasn't described in the first place. There's no reason to use such an expression, either in MySQL or T-SQL. What are you trying to do? What does the query look like? Have you checked what that statement does to performance, in either database?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's just a way to debug or test the SQL when developing, I'm not using it in the program. Thank you.